# How can I make custom navigation bar using ReactNative?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am making social application using React Native.

I want to know how can I make custom navigation bar like something IOS and Android.

It should be have with color navigation bar and image button.

Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple react native navigation libraries. Personally, I use the Wix one: https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/

It should cover what you need.